# Windows Driver: Input and Output

Tags: windows, driver, native

I'm reading about windows drivers and in the resources I read, input is generally done by a user program calling `WriteFile` on the devices file and output is done by a user program calling `ReadFile` (or by `DbgPrint`).

Is it possible for a device to get input directly from keyboard and outputing directly to the screen without interfering with display/keyboard drivers?

More specifically, let's say I'd like to write a driver working as following. Whenever the F10 key is pressed everything freezes and the screen becomes red; pressing F10 again restores everything. How would I do it?

Comment: look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268199/using-haldisplaystring-for-custom-blue-screen-of-death

Answer (score 0):

Very short answer,

> Whenever the F10 key is pressed everything freezes

You may want to write keyboard class filter to read keys pressed. [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Kbfiltr-WDF-Version-685ff5c4) is sample

> the screen becomes red

You may want to write display/monitor filter driver. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)